# How to find the $\int_C xe^{x+y} dx + ye^{x+y} dy -ze^z dz$ by Stoke's theorem?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

$R = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert \ 0 \leq x+y  \leq 1, 0\leq x-y\leq 1\}$ and $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x+y+z=3\}$. Let the simply closed curve $C = S \cap \partial R$. (Here  $\partial R$ is the boundary of the $R$). Find the value of the  $\int_C xe^{x+y} dx + ye^{x+y} dy -ze^z dz$ .

I'm trying to find this value applying the stoke's theorem. Let the $F = (xe^{x+y}, ye^{x+y},-ze^z)$ Then $curlF = (0,0,(y-x)e^{x+y})$. By the stoke's theorem, $\int_c F\cdot T ds = \int\int curlF\cdot N dxdy$.

Since the intersection lied on the plane, $N= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$, So my conclusion is
$\int\int_{0\leq x+y\leq1, 0\leq x-y \leq 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(y-x)e^{x+y} dx dy $
Therefore, By integral by substitution $ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\int\int_{0\leq u\leq1, 0\leq v \leq  1}(-u)e^{v} du dv $ for $u=x-y$ and $v=x+y$.

But the solution suggested $ \frac{1}{2}\int\int_{0\leq u\leq1, 0\leq v \leq  1}(-u)e^{v} du dv $. Plus I've understood why the answer suggest like that. But my biggest question is I can't find which point I made mistakes. Please let me know.

Regards.

Comment: I think you left out the Jacobian for your substitution.

Comment: @B.Goddard, Thanks for your comment. :) But I don't think I left out the Jacobian. Because $u=x-y$ and $v = x+y$, Jacobian would be $1/2 = \vert \begin{vmatrix}
x_u & x_v  \\ y_u & y_v  \\\end{vmatrix} \vert $  for computing by $dudv$

Comment: I think you used the Stokes theorem incorrectly. It should be $$\int_c F\cdot T ds = \int_S curlF\cdot N dS,$$ a surface integral, not just a double integral.

Comment: No. $\int_S f(x,y,z)\,dS$ means the surface integral, it should be computed using the equation for the surface $S$, see the first formula [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx). Are you sure the solution manual suggesting $\frac1{\sqrt 3}$, rather than $\frac12$?

Comment: @Feng, Thanks for your comment though question I deleted. (In fact, I need more time to contemplate for that. So I deleted it.) Plus As your comment, The solution manual suggest 1/2 not $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$. That was a typo. I edited.

Comment: Now it seems that your understanding about Stokes theorem needs to be improved. [This webpage](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/StokesTheorem.aspx) may be helpful. Pay more attention on Example 2, especially on the line containing $\frac{\nabla f}{\|\nabla f\|} \|\nabla f\|$. Fight it!

Comment: In $ \displaystyle \int_C F\cdot T ~ds = \iint  curlF\cdot \vec n ~dx ~dy$, $\vec n$ is not unit normal vector! If the surface is given by $z = f(x, y) = 3 - x - y$, then the normal vector is $(- f_x, - f_y, 1)$

Comment: Hint: if $g=(x+y-1)e^{x+y}+(1-z)e^z$, what is $dg$?